# bash script unable to get the variable

Tags: bash, for-loop, scripting, awk, cut

On command line this works like this:

```
svn log "$src_url" --stop-on-copy \
  | awk -v RS="--+" -F'|' ' /ticket-101/{print $1}' \
  | grep "^r" \
  | cut -d"r" -f2 \
  | cut -d" " -f1
```

Output:

```
6359
6358
6263
6241
6240
6239
6238
6237
6236
```

The script works when hard code the ticket number but does not when i assign it as variable. I might have to give more than one tickets hence need this to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

src_url="$1"
itrack=ticket-101

for ticket in "$itrack"; do
echo $ticket
revs=($(IFS=$'\n';
        svn log "$src_url" --stop-on-copy \
          | awk -v RS="--+" -F'|' ' /"$ticket"/{print $1}' \
          | grep "^r" \
          | cut -d"r" -f2 \
          | cut -d" " -f1 \
          | sort -r
      ))

for revision in ${!revs[*]} ; do

  echo ${revs[$revision]}
done

done
```

`Output gives nothing.`

The output of the `svn` command I am trying to parse is:

```
 $ svn log http://test.svn.com/svn/demo_project --limit 5

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r1000 | testuser25 | 2013-06-13 13:37:10 -0400 (Thu, 13 Jun 2013) | 1 line

 ticket-1135
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r999 | testuser20 | 2013-06-13 13:26:46 -0400 (Thu, 13 Jun 2013) | 2 lines

 ticket-1135
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r998 | testuser30 | 2013-06-13 12:12:12 -0400 (Thu, 13 Jun 2013) | 1 line

 ticket-122
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r997 | testuser25 | 2013-06-13 12:09:56 -0400 (Thu, 13 Jun 2013) | 1 line

 ticket-11
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r900 | testuser40 | 2013-06-13 12:09:53 -0400 (Thu, 13 Jun 2013) | 1 line

 ticket-113
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If input is: `/run.sh http://test.svn.com/svn/demo_project ticket-1135 ticket-122 ticket-113`

The desired output would be:

```
900
998
999
1000
```

Comment: `' /$ticket/{print $1}'` won't expand in single quotes try double quotes

Comment: Show us you input and your expected output, easier to rewrite the whole thing tbh... that is not the way you want to be doing this (or anything).

Comment: Updated it now - both the commandline output and how i wrote the script.

Comment: Double quotes also did not work.

Comment: Check my answer to see how you should use double quotes; your post shows the use of double quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: Do it like this `' /"'$ticket'"/{print $1}'`. Note that `$ticket` is outside the single quotes so that shell can expand it. But `$1` is inside single quotes because we don't want shell to expand that.

Comment: Why the exclamation sign in `${!revs[*]}`? I guess you only want to loop through your array and print the content... AND correct syntax is `${revs[@]}` to loop through an array. To debug, change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/bash -x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass in the value of a shell script variable into `awk` you should the `-v` option like so:

```
awk -v tick="$ticket" -v RS="--+" -F'|' ' $0~tick{print $1}'
```

Do not do what [**unxnut**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17092409/1066031) suggests as `$1` will be interpreted as the first argument to the script and **not** the first field in the record by `awk`.

---

This may solve your problem temporarily but your script has some very bad practices in it and to get some actual help you should tell us what you are trying to do, show the input and the expected output and we can show the right approach.

Comment: I'm trying to get revisions in version control based on the tickets used to checkin/commits and redirect the output to a file. I just need the revision numbers

Comment: Your comment doesn't help - Edit the question and **tell us what you are trying to do, show the input and the expected output.** Also please un-accept @unxnut answers as the information is incorrect.

Comment: sudo_O - edit the question with intended input and desired output. Hope the info is explained properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the list of revisions

```
revs=($(svn log "$src_url" --stop-on-copy \ 
         | awk -v RS='--+\n' -F'|' '/'"$ticket"'\n/{sub(/^r| $/,""); print $1}'
     ))
```

- Note: I use `awk`'s `sub()` to get rid of the leading `r` and the trailing space behind the revision number.

---

If you want to loop through all the revisions

```
for revisions in "${revisions[@]}"; do
    echo $revisions
done
```